# How to using Like with Text in FMDB query iOS Swift 4?

Tags: ios, sql, swift, sql-like, fmdb

I wanna get query with **like** and try like this:

```
let name = "pp" //apple

let db = openDB()
  do {
      var queryString = "select * from products where name like '%?%' and deleted = 0 order by id desc"
      let rs = try db.executeQuery(queryString, values:[name])
      var arr:Array<Product> = []
      while rs.next() {
      arr.append(parseProductDB(rs))
      }
      closeDB(db)
} catch {
      print("failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
      closeDB(db)
}
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this:

```
let db = openDB()
do {
    var queryString =
    queryString = String(format:"select * from products where name like '%%%@%%' and deleted = 0 order by id desc",name)
    let rs = try db.executeQuery(queryString, values:nil)
    var arr:Array<Product> = []
    while rs.next() {
    arr.append(parseProductDB(rs))
    }
    closeDB(db)

} catch {
            print("failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            closeDB(db)
}
```

Comment: even if it works you should always try using parameters like you did in your code. That makes your code less vulnerable to potential script injection and lets you a chance to create prepared query statements that run faster in database.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me (swift 4, Xcode 9):

```
let texto_like : String = "%\(texto)%"

let sql = "select * from TABLE where MY_COLUMN like ? COLLATE NOCASE"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the parameter in your SQL statement with `?` and wrap your passed value with SQL wildcard characters, like this:

```
let name = "%pp%"
...
var queryString = "select * from products where name like ? and deleted = 0 order by id desc"
```

The reason is in SQLite and possibly in every other SQL engine a parameter is a complete entity consisting its value and type information. So wrapping parameter within quotes (') like `'%?%'` is never required and is actually a wrong practice.

Also `like` operator expects merely a string expression as it operand that might contain SQL wildcard character if needed. So you just need to create a string expression with embedded wildcard characters (%, _, etc) and pass it to your statement when required.

Comment: did it really worked for you? I also faced same issue before

Comment: I know it is not working but if this solution might work that will solve my issues. I also tried like /%pp/% but didnt get desired output. If you find any answer or solution please post it here for someone like me. @reza_khalafi

Comment: @JitendraModi & @raza_khalafi frankly it I never tried this in Swift. In Objective-C I have to declare the variable like, `NSString *name = @"%%pp%%"` and it works gracefully without any glitch. I have to use `%%` in Objective-C since `%` alone is a format specifier for that language and should be escaped with  another percent sign (`%%`). I don't know if that holds true for Swift as well. But you might give it a try.

Comment: Yeah, sure we will give it a try but thanks for your reply. Grateful to you